# C program for removing duplicate characters in a string...Shows run time error

Tags: c, string, duplicates

I wrote the following function for removing duplicate characters from a string..For ex: if 
       str = "heeello;
        removeDuplicate(str)

will return helo...But it shows some error on runtime .I have added some printf() statements for debugging...Can anyone tell me what the problem is ?

```
char* removeDuplicate(char str[])//remove duplicate characters from a string,so that each character in                a string is not repeating  
{
    int i = 0,j;
    char ch;
    printf("\nstr is %s",str);
    while((ch = str[i++] )!= '\0')
    {
    j = i;
    printf("\n----ch = %c----",ch);
    while(str[j] != '\0')
    {
        printf("\n--------Checking whether %c =  %c \n",str[j],ch);
        if(ch == str[j])
        {
            printf("\n------------Yes");
            while(str[j]!='\0')
            { 
                printf("\nRemoving %c %d -- \n",str[j]);
                str[j] = str[++j];
                --i;

            }

            break;
        }
        printf("\n------------No");

       //printf("\njj");
        j++;
    }
}

return str;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your call to this function?

Comment: removeDuplicate("heee");

Comment: yes that was the problem with call...heee doesnot have \0 :P..Is it the problem?

Comment: Actually, it does have `\0` "heee" is just like {'h', 'e', 'e', 'e', '\0'}

Comment: Your code contains (at least) two dangerous styles, which probably cause this function to behave different than you have in mind: Dont use a variable and ++ it in the same expression: `str[j] = str[++j];`. The C specification doesn't specify how the compiler should behave in this case (see http://c-faq.com/expr/evalorder1.html). Also doing `i--` is not a very wise thing to do in such constructions. In this case `i` will become negative in a lot of cases, and `str[-1]` is clearly not valid here.

Comment: it is not working for "muuuuuuurat" ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a string literal, which you are not allowed to modify to this function, instead you should do:

```
char myStr[] = "heee";
removeDuplicate(myStr);
```

Also, please note that in the following lines your have to specifiers inside the printf (`%c %d`), but you pass only one argument (`str[j]`):

```
printf("\nRemoving %c %d -- \n",str[j]);
```

This may cause all sorts of bad things...

Comment: actually i printed j also with that ...it is an accidental mistake...also what is the problem in logic?

Comment: Yes got the actual logic problem and changed the while loop as
    while(str[j] != '\0')
        {
            if(ch == str[j])
            {
                while(str[j]!='\0')
                    str[j] = str[++j];
                 i--;
                break;
            }
            j++;
        }

Answer (score 2):

You should correct your code as follows:

```
  In first while loop:  j = i+1;
  In third while loop: i--; // is not required
  Remove that unwanted specifier form printf("Removing %d %d:",str[j])

  Doing incorrectly :
  str[j] = str[++j] // you are increasing j before assigning
  str[j] = str[j++] // correct way to do.But it is compiler dependent i guess

  Better to use:
    t = j;
    str[t] = str[++j];
```

Comment: I have changed the bug  and posted as comment for Binyamin Sharet 's answer see that..

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this function does what you want. The remove loop is really fishy.. you decrement `i` which looks wrong.. and you increment `j` which is probably also wrong:

```
while(str[j]!='\0')
{ 
  printf("\nRemoving %c %d -- \n",str[j]);
  str[j] = str[++j]; // now the new character is at location j, but since
  // you incremented j you can't access it anymore
  --i; // why is i dependent on the remove stuff?
}
```

I would go for a simpler approach. Create a large bool array. Loop through your string and store whether you already encountered the current character or not. If not, print it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following code :

```
char* removeDuplicate(char str[])//remove duplicate characters from a string,so that each character in                a string is not repeating  
{
int i = 0,j;
char ch;
int repIndex=0;
int temp=0;
printf("\nstr is %s",str);
while((ch = str[i++] )!= '\0')
{
j = i;
printf("\n----ch = %c----",ch);
while(str[j] != '\0')
{
    printf("\n--------Checking whether %c =  %c \n",str[j],ch);
    repIndex = j;
    if(ch == str[repIndex])
    {
        printf("\n------------Yes");
        while(str[repIndex]!='\0')
        {
            printf("\nRemoving %c %d \n",str[j]);
            temp = repIndex;
            str[temp] = str[++repIndex];

        }

    } else { j++; }

    }
}

return str;
}


int main ( int argc, char ** argv)
{

    char myStr[]="asdfhelllasdfloofdoeohz";

    printf ("OUtput is : %s \n", removeDuplicate(myStr)  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//removing the redundant characters in a string
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int  i=0,j,arr[26]={},temp;     //array for hashing
 char  s[10],arr1[10],*p;      //array 4 storing d output string
 printf("Enter the string\n");
 scanf("%s",s);
 p=s;
 while(*p!='\0')
 {
     temp=((*p)>92)?(*p)-'a':(*p)-'A';  //asuming lowr and upr letters are same 
    if(arr[temp]==0)              //if it is not hashed ie if that char is not repeated
    {
     arr1[i]=temp+'a';              //return the string in lowecase
     arr[temp]=1;          //storing value so that this character sd not be placed again
     i++;
    }
    p++;                          //else ignore the alphabet
 }
 for(j=0;j<i;j++)
   {
    printf("%c",arr1[j]);          //print the string stored in arr1
   }
 return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected the code as follows

```
char* removeDuplicate(char str[])//remove duplicate characters from a string,so that each character in a string is not repeating
{
    int i = 0,j;
    char ch;
    while((ch = str[i++] )!= '\0')
    {
        j = i;
        while(str[j] != '\0')
        {
            if(ch == str[j])
            {
                while(str[j]!='\0')
                str[j] = str[++j];
                 i--;
                break;
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
   return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
clrscr();
char *str;
int count=0;
cout<<"enter the string which have repetative characters"<<endl;
cin>>str;
char *str2;
int m=0;
for(int i=0;i<=strlen(str);i++)
{
char ch=str[i];

if(i==0)
{
str2[m]=str[i];
m++;
}
for(int j=0;j<=strlen(str2);j++)
{
if(ch==str2[j])
count++;
}
if(count==0)
{
str2[m]=str[i];
m++;
}
count=0;
if(i==strlen(str))
str2[m]='\0';
}

puts(str2);
getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**O(n) complexity**

```
char *removeDuplicates(char *str){
    int hash[256]        =  {0};
    int currentIndex     = 0;
    int lastUniqueIndex  = 0;
    while(*(str+currentIndex)){
        char temp = *(str+currentIndex);
        if(0 == hash[temp]){
            hash[temp] = 1;
            *(str+lastUniqueIndex) = temp;
            lastUniqueIndex++;
        }
        currentIndex++;
    }
    *(str+lastUniqueIndex) = '\0';
    return str;
}
```

Refer: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-all-duplicates-from-the-input-string/