# removing all repeated characters from string in c

Tags: c, string, duplicates

I want to remove all the repeated characters from a string. For example, if I have:

```
"abcdabef"
```

I want the result to be

```
"cdef"
```

I have tried with loops, but it's getting me confusing. Can anyone just tell me how to do this?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
    char s[20],ch,*p;
    int i,j,k,cnt;
    puts("enter string:");
    gets(s);
    for(i=0;s[i];i++)
    {
    ch=s[i];
    for(cnt=0,j=0;s[j];j++)
    {
            if(ch==s[j])
            cnt++;
            if(cnt>1)
            {
            for(k=0;s[k]==ch;k++)
            {
            strcpy(s+k,s+k+1);
            if(s[k]==ch)
            {k--;}
            }
            if(s[j-1]==ch)
            j--;
            }
    }
    }
    puts(s);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C program for removing duplicate characters in a string...Shows run time error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665425/c-program-for-removing-duplicate-characters-in-a-string-shows-run-time-error)

Comment: `main()`'s signature is not `main()` but either `int main(void)` or `int main(int, char **)` (on a hosted implementation). Also, **do use whitespace.** But **do NOT use `gets()`,** because it is **inherently insecure.** Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: @jycr753 as a general rule, it seems unhelpful to use debugging questions as dupe closure targets for "how should I implement this?" questions. Even if it's possible to piece together a solution from the linked question and its answers, it's unlikely to provide the best solution and the two questions are asking fundamentally different things.

Comment: @MarkAmery Its hard to pick since there is a lot references to something similar, since it just need a bit more of research to find it...

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I would just count the characters in the string and print out those which appear exactly once in the string.

```
char buf[BUFSIZE]; // whatever the size is

// get user input
if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin))
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // couldn't fgets()

size_t len = strlen(buf);

int counts[1 << CHAR_BIT] = { 0 };

// count each character
for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    unsigned char ch = buf[i];
    counts[ch]++;
}

// print those which are present exactly once
for (size_t i = 0; i < 1 << CHAR_BIT; i++) {
    if (counts[i] == 1) {
        printf("%c", (unsigned char)(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't want to print the repeated characters.so i want to remove all the repeated characters...so i want to print those non-repetitive characters in string.

Comment: @Kumar2080 And that's exactly what my code does. **Read** the first sentence in my answer. This code only prints out the characters which are **not** repeated.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* remRepeatedChars(char *str)
{
  char arr[128] = {0};
  char *tmp = str;

  while((*str) != '\0')
  {
    char *p = str;

    while(arr[*p] != 0 && *p != '\0')
      p++; // found repetition

    if(str != p) // the previous while was entered
      *str = *p; //Copy the content of p to str.

    arr[*str]++;    
    str++;
  }
  return tmp;
}
```