# how to print out only unduplicated charaters in a string?

Tags: c

I have spend 2 days trying to figure out how can I print out only unduplicate character in a string
for example: input: `aaddbe`
output: `be`

here's what I have try

```
void removestring(char o[], int k, int n){

    int i;
    for(i=k; i<n; i++){
    o[i]=o[i+1];
    }
    n--;
    }
    main(){
    char o[1000];
    int i, j, len, check=0; 
    char lastD;
    gets(o);
    len = strlen(o);
        puts(o);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        check=0;
        for(j=len-1;j>i;j--){
            if(o[i]==o[j]) {
            check = 1;
            removestring(o, j, len); 
            }
        }
        if(check==1){
        removestring(o, i, len);
        }
        printf("%c", o[i]);
        }
    }
```

but this is not seem to work as it only can print out ddbe from the example.

Comment: Why not have a counter array and avoid printing if you've already seen that character before?

Comment: Create two array for a~z ( or a~zA~Z ). One for occurrence and one for index. Run through string once and get both index and occurrence, then print by index.

Comment: @tadman It seems the spec is that never print duplicated characters. Though title is a bit misleading. Since `aaddbe` becomes `be`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [removing all repeated characters from string in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460454/removing-all-repeated-characters-from-string-in-c)

Comment: @LouisGo Still achievable with a count, then a second pass to print.

Answer (score 2):

- `i` is advanced even after deleting duplicate characters, so duplicate characters just after duplicate characters aren't checked.
- Modifications to `n` in the function `removestring` won't influence variables in `main` function. You should use pointers to do this modification.
- You shouldn't use `gets()`, which has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun, deprecated in C99 and removed from C11.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void removestring(char o[], int k, int *n){

    int i;
    for(i=k; i<*n; i++){
        o[i]=o[i+1];
    }
    (*n)--;
}
int main(void){
    char o[1000];
    int i, j, len, check=0; 
    char lastD;
    char *lf;
    fgets(o, sizeof(o), stdin);
    if ((lf = strchr(o, '\n')) != NULL) *lf = '\0';
    len = strlen(o);
    puts(o);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        check=0;
        for(j=len-1;j>i;j--){
            if(o[i]==o[j]) {
                check = 1;
                removestring(o, j, &len); 
            }
        }
        if(check==1){
            removestring(o, i, &len);
            i--;
        } else {
            printf("%c", o[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is optimized way

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        char a[] = "aaddbe";
        
        int count[26] = {0}; //intitlized all element to zero
        
        for(int i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++){
            count[a[i]-97]++;
        }
        
        for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
           //cout<<count[i]<<" ";
            if(count[i]==1){
                cout<<(char)(i+97);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It's worth doing a range check on the character so you don't overflow the array, or set the array to be 256 long so you can't miss.

Comment: Totally Agree! Thanks